# How to find all fields with same value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Say we have the table below

```
Name Date                 reg_no
aa   12/12/2013 10:13:15  rty003
aa   13/12/2013 11:14:16  jyu887
bb   13/14/2013 09:45:10  rty003
bb   12/12/2013 10:13:27  rty003
```

i want to display only the names that have matching reg_no and date values (without seconds).
The result should be as shown below.

```
Name1 Name2  Date              reg_no
aa    bb     12/12/2013 10:13  rty003
```

How can i achieve this in oracle?

Comment: You can achieve more easily the result `aa, bb | 12/12/2013 10:13  | rty003`. Is it suitable  for you?

Comment: Yeah, how can i do it?

Comment: Which version of Oracle do you use?

Comment: Remember this is just a sample. The table is so huge and i only know the aa,bb names. For date and reg_no, i have to use a query that can match the fields based on names (aa,bb)

Answer (score 2):

Try with `listagg` function:

```
SELECT listagg( NAME,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY NAME), 
       to_char(date_time,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 
       reg_no 
FROM t
GROUP BY to_char(date_time,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), reg_no
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be better but worth,

```
WITH TAB(NAME,DDATE, REG_NO) AS (
SELECT 'aa', TO_DATE('12/12/2013 10:13:15', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'rty003' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aa', TO_DATE('03/12/2013 11:14:16', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'jyu887' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bb', TO_DATE('03/14/2013 09:45:10', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'rty003' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bb', TO_DATE('12/12/2013 10:13:27', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'rty003' FROM DUAL),
----------------
-- End of Data Preparation
----------------
TAB2 AS 
(SELECT NAME, 
        TRUNC(DDATE, 'MI') DDATE, 
        REG_NO, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRUNC(DDATE, 'MI'), REG_NO ORDER BY NAME) RN,
        COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY TRUNC(DDATE, 'MI'), REG_NO) CNT
    FROM TAB) 
SELECT MIN(DECODE(RN, 1, NAME, NULL)) NAME1,
       MIN(DECODE(RN, 2, NAME, NULL)) name2,
       DDATE,
       REG_NO
  FROM TAB2
 WHERE CNT = 2
 group by ddate, reg_no;
```

Output:

```
| NAME1 | NAME2 |                           DDATE | REG_NO |
|-------|-------|---------------------------------|--------|
|    aa |    bb | December, 12 2013 10:13:00+0000 | rty003 |
```

Your final query will be

```
WITH TAB2 AS 
(SELECT NAME, 
        TRUNC(DDATE, 'MI') DDATE, 
        REG_NO, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRUNC(DDATE, 'MI'), REG_NO ORDER BY NAME) RN,
        COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY TRUNC(DDATE, 'MI'), REG_NO) CNT
    FROM <your_table_name>) 
SELECT MIN(DECODE(RN, 1, NAME, NULL)) NAME1,
       MIN(DECODE(RN, 2, NAME, NULL)) name2,
       DDATE,
       REG_NO
  FROM TAB2
 WHERE CNT = 2
 group by ddate, reg_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(NAME),MAX(NAME), 
    TRUNC(DDATE, 'MI'), 
    REG_NO
FROM tab
GROUP BY  
    TRUNC(DDATE, 'MI'), 
    REG_NO
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: The op wants to display all the names that matches.